# How to make request from asp.net core web app to self

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

Lets suppose I have a bunch of controllers which renders text parts. They are accessible via urls from a browser. But some of them are just a composition of others. What I want is request several texts and concat it. Why?

- They are required time to construct, but highly probably already cached
- Do not invent my own cache and use ASP.NET one

Probably I could `System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString("https://myserver/path")` however it is inefficient.

---

@derloopkat below kindly asked me about code sample

```
[ApiController]
[Route("foo")]
public abstract class FooController: ControllerBase
{   
   [HttpGet]
   public string Get()
   {
     return "foo";
   }
}

[ApiController]
[Route("bar")]
public abstract class BarController: ControllerBase
{   
   [HttpGet]
   public string Get()
   {
      return "bar";
   }
}

[ApiController]
[Route("bar_plus_foo")]
public abstract class CompositeController: ControllerBase
{   
   [HttpGet]
   public string Get()
   {
      // TODO: how to fetch result of FooController and BarController 
      // to return concatenation?       
   }
}
```

Comment: that's a bad architeture behavior. migrate your business code to isolated classes. logic should not be inside your controllers. logic should be in service classes.

Answer (score 2):

we usually do not write business logic in controllers like this.
you can create a service and hide your business logic in that service. the code would be like this:

```
public class BarService
{
    public string GenerateBar(string param)
    {
        return "bar";
        //Or any business logic that you have
    }
}
```

for example you can search for onion architecture and see examples in github
by the way dont make controllers abstract.
hope this helps